# Getting configuration failure while executing TestNG xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am running the `TestNG` xml and test is failing with configuration failure error.

**TestNG xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue">
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.inetbanking.utilities.Reporting" />
    </listeners>
  <test name="Test">
  <parameter name="broswer" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
     <!--  <class name="com.inetbanking.testCases.TC_LoginDDT_002"/> -->
      <class name="com.inetbanking.testCases.TC_LoginTest_001"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**Error**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried? If you haven't already, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page

Comment: Have you added the log4j to buildpath ?

Comment: Where is the error? I can only see the warnings.